# MySQL Access denied for my application, but others work fine

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to connect to my MySQL Database remotely through my application to exchange some data. It works if I compile my C# code for Ubuntu and run it locally. But when I try to run it out of Visual Studio to use the debugger, I get the error

```
Access denied for user 'jackilion'@'192.168.1.110' (using password: YES)
```

My user jackilion has ALL privileges

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'jackilion'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '*****';
```

And furthermore, I can connect using DBeaver or other database programms using the same user and from the very same computer.

Soo... My code should be correct, since I can connect with it if I run it on the machine where MySQL is installed, but my MySQL settings should also be correct, since I can remotely connect from my laptop?!
I am desperate, please help me.

Thank you,
Jack

**EDIT**
My ConnectionString:

```
static string ConnectionInfo =  "server=192.168.1.114;" + 
                                    "database=Data;"+
                                    "username=jackilion;"+
                                    "password=*****";
```

The only thing I change when running on the Ubuntu machine is changing the server address to "localhost".

Comment: why do you change it to localhost on ubuntu? i `192.168.1.114` the ubuntu machine itself?

Comment: Yes, MySQL is running on my ubuntu machine which is 192.168.1.114

Comment: Just out of interest, on the Ubuntu machine can you connect using 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost for the server. _"Localhost is handled differently by MySQL, as it goes through the local unix socket instead of the network interface."_ - so you are not really comparing similar types of connection.

Comment: Yes. I can connect to 'localhost', to '127.0.0.1' and to '192.168.1.114' (which is the Ubuntu machines IP) from the Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally got it... It's a really dumb error that's completely on me.
my password included the character '§', which somehow works differently when I send it to the Ubuntu machine, than when I'm using it directly on the machine. I changed the password and it works now.